# Cant access localhost/xampp to change root password

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I cannot get onto localhost/xampp to change the password for root as I keep getting the error in php about root not having a password.
I've tried command line, changing password in phpadmin which ends up ruining everything and having to reinstall xampp.

tried localhost/xampp
local../8080
local../80

Comment: It's probably not complaining about root not having a password, it's probably complaining about using root without a password. It's a very bad idea to use root when connecting via code, anyway. Create a user/pass in mysql/phpmyadmin, then use that user/pass combo in your code.

Comment: @aynber "You are connected as 'root' with no password, which corresponds to the default MySQL privileged account. " is the exact error

Comment: This is why exact error messages are helpful. Where are you getting this in PHP? In PHPMyAdmin? If it's your code, I still recommend creating a new non-root user/pass and using that for your code.